# QGIS:When exporting a print layout as a .svg, the entire map gets exported

Tags: qgis

I have a problem, I'm using QGis 3.2.3, when I make a print layout an put a map on it

[image]
, if I use some projections (in this case albert projection focused on canada), then export it as a .svg, the entire map gets exported [image] resulting in a very heavy vector file that is hardly usable. However if I export it as a picture, it works [image] and only shows what is inside the frame, furthermore I don't encounter this problem if use some other projection, like platte carree.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a glitch?

Comment: I think it is still an issue that it is not yet solved and maybe related to QT: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227844/qgis-composer-svg-wrong-rendering

Comment: May be update to qgis 3.4.1 ?

Comment: Alright thanks for the answers! I did update to 3.4.1 but it didn't change anything, on this thread you linked i tried to use it but as they warned, it doesn't work with curved projections, and sadly in my case this is only a problem about specific curved projection. 

The suggestion to export as a .pdf works! The only small problem is that it doesn't separate various layers in QGIS into layers with inkscape/illustrator, but it's a comparatively minor problem.